# Where is adb in Android 6? Is it removed?

Tags: android, adb, android-6.0-marshmallow

I use a terminal emulator on my mobile phone to connect to other Android devices via adb (Android Debug Bridge).

The connect command is:

```
/system/bin/adb connect 192.168.179.12
```

This works fine on Android 5 and below versions. But on Android 6 (Marshmallow) I get the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
```

When I browse the file system on my Android 6 phone I cannot find adb at this path. On older Android versions I can find adb at this location.

Did Google remove adb from Android 6 ? Where is adb on Android 6 devices?

Comment: They seem to have removed it....

Comment: I was afraid of this bad news :-(

Comment: I have not used it yet, but I think you need to install it

Comment: @Empario are you sure? In Android 5 and below it used to be part of the OS. How to install on my mobile without root?

Comment: I do not have phone supporting Marshmallow yet. Therefore I am not able to try it out. Have tried **adb shell adb**?

Comment: Every adb command gives me a "java.io.IOException: No such file or directory" . This happens on marshmallow devices only !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as of android 6.0, the compilation of adb for 'device-on-target' was removed. 
[here is my question on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521706/compile-for-android-6-0-adb-for-device-on-target)
Don't know why it was removed, but i hope that in the near future they will add the compilation of it.

Comment: It's a pity. Would be interesting to know why they removed it. I already miss it !