# Nexus 9 (OS -6) adb connection over tcp not Working

Tags: android, debugging, tcp, wifi, adb

After upgrading my device to Marshmallow, I am unable to connect my device on tcpip for wifi debugging (It used to work on Lollipop). IP is my device IP address.

```
platform-tools>adb connect IP:5555
```

I am getting below message

```
unable to connect to IP:5555
```

I also tried to connect on 7612 port.

Comment: please add your complete flow. Did you ran 'adb tcpip 5555' before? are your device and PC on the same subnet?

Comment: @DanMordechai Yes I follow these steps  1.Connect both devices on same network on wifi 2. connect my android tablet 3. go to platform-tools 4. adb tcpip 5555 I am getting message as restarting in Tcp mode port :5555  5. I disconnect my android device 6. adb connect IP:5555 These are the steps I am following

Comment: Try to enable hotspot on your android device and connect directly to it with your PC. Then try your flow again. Any changes?

Comment: I have the same problem with nexus 9 and marshmellow. If I try to connect acoording to this http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#wireless, the error is: "cannot connect to #.#.#.#:5555: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10060)". Other devices works well (Asus phone, OnePlus One). If I try wrong port (eg 5554), it returns:  "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)". "kill-server" didn't help

Answer (score 2):

5555 is the port number which is not used while connecting. Connection takes place in to steps:

1. Set port on which connection is to be stablished(in this case 5555)
2. Connect to the device using it's IP address.

So let's say your device IP is 192.168.1.1 and you want to connect over port 5555,

1. `adb tcpip 5555`
2. `adb connect 192.168.1.1`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get unable to connect to ``<<IP Address>>:5555: cannot connect to <<IP Address>>:5555:
 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respon
d after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected hos
t has failed to respond. (10060)``

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

1. Make sure that Aggressive Wi-Fi to Cellular handover under Networking section in the device's developer options is turned off.
2. ping continuously from your pc to the device to make sure it's not in network idle mode 
   ping -t 192.168.1.10 (windows cmd), unlock the device and even try to surf to some 
   website just to make it get out of the network idle.
3. If ping doesn't work, turn off / on Android Wifi and go back to step 2.
4. When it replies to the ping, connect it via usb, and:

   adb usb

   adb tcpip 5555

   adb connect 192.168.10.1:5555
5. In case it's still not connected, try to switch the usb connection mode as MTP / PTP / 
   Camera while the device is connected through usb and repeat these steps over again...

   If the above points are not working please try running adb as admin. For Ubuntu -

   `sudo adb start-server`
   as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33462720/adb-unable-to-connect-to-192-168-1-105555)