# Is there are way to check adb connection logs on my device?

Tags: android

I have an Android device which I do development on. When I had a stock ROM, I could always connect with WiFi. However, I switched to a custom root rom and *whatever I do* (and believe I did all) it does not connect to the device over WiFi, saying:

```
failed to connect to '192.168.1.2:5555': Connection refused
```

Believe I did all that. Trying with sudo, playing with developer settings on custom root rom, restarting, killing server and starting server and plugging it in again. None of them worked. I have done all the solutions [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33462720/adb-unable-to-connect-to-192-168-1-105555) and many other questions and blog posts.

That's why what I'm asking is something different. I'd like to troubleshoot it myself. Now, the question is:

**Is there a way to see adb connection debug/trace logs on my device** so that I can at least tell what the problem is? Where are these logs located?

Thanks in advance.

---

## Environment

- Android 9
- General Mobile GM5 Plus
- Custom Root Rom

```
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 31.0.2-7242960
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering to your particular question you can view the android logcat if you have root access there are plenty of applications to do so: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sinoka.apps.logcatviewer&hl=es&gl=US

Related with your problems connecting to adb over wifi, is very hard to tell where the problem is, cause of the custom rom, on android 11 and posterior is simplier because we have an option to pair devices and works very good.

Comment: I have also tried `adb logcat` but `adb connect` errors seems to be not dropping logs there.

Comment: I also think that using the logcat to debug errors produced by adb connect is not useful :/