# Cross Compile ADB , How to convert Android.mk to MakeFile?

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk

## Preface

I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040693/how-to-rewrite-the-makefile-into-android-mk) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521706/compile-for-android-6-0-adb-for-device-on-target) and STFW before I ask.
Because of ROM's Difference , I want to cross compile an ADB server(N+) running on my aarch64 device from the [adb source code].

You can see here for the difference changes of android.mk in the following lines:

[Latest Android 7.+ version](https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/master/adb/Android.mk)
, [Lollipop Android 5.+ version](https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/lollipop-release/adb/Android.mk) This Version contains adb for device-on-target feature.

## Question

I can't find a proper MakeFile and it's just a Android.mk in the folder.How should I convert it to makefile in order to using `make` to build a adb for device-on-target. I've already built a cross compiling environment and installed the `ndk-build`,`repo`,`build-essential` on my ubuntu 16.04 lts.

Or on the other hand, can I only build ADB for device-on-target without compiling the whole rom?Which argument should I use with `ndk-build`?Please give me more detailed info and caution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instructions on setting up a platform build environment are on the AOSP website: http://source.android.com/source/requirements.html

The ADB client program is not configured to be built *for* the device. We only support that for hosts. If you want to build it for the device, you'll need to add that build configuration (see system/core/adb/Android.mk) and then most likely do some porting work to get it functioning.

Comment: I just want to compile an unusual adb, because of soe reason,google removed adb for device-on-target and i need to run a adb on my phone(equals to device-on-target).so how can i bring it back?

Comment: You asked how to convert it to a makefile that can be invoked with just make. You don't. Follow the build instructions on the AOSP site. You can run `make` at the top level of the tree or you can run `mma` in a specific project.

Comment: if I use `make adb` at the top level of the tree, It will the the x86_64 platform's gcc.How can I let it use the `aarch64-linux-android-<gcc-version>` ?

Comment: Extended my answer to cover the bit about adb on the device.

Comment: If the hosts is an ARM device,what should I do?e.g. Raspberry Pi

Comment: You'll have to port adb, including the build system. This isn't something the AOSP build system supports at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at my commits but I had to make quite a few changes.

https://github.com/Surge1223/android_system_core/blob/android-7.1/adb/Android.mk

builds statically for both arm and arm64

Comment: I'll have a try.Could you please give me a guide to build using your source code?can I just 'make adb' ?

Comment: after syncing aosp you'll have to cherry-pick a few of the commits I made in /system/core  and then when you type make adb it will make adb for both host and target by default

Comment: Thx a lot.Can I just clone your repo and replace the original file?I entered the code review for AOSP but didn't see the pull request you added.However,Which commits should I cherry-pick if I can replace the original files?